# Backbone Communication between collection and model

Tags: backbone.js

Lets say I have a model of (audio/video) tracks and a collection those tracks of it

**Model:**

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults:{...},
   play: function() {
      //plays the track
   }
});
```

The collection then represents something like a playlist with

**Collection:**

```
Backbone.Collections.extend({
   currentTrackInList: 0,
   model: track,
   playAll: function() {
      self = this;
      this.models.each(function(item){
         item[self.currentTrackInList].play();
      });
   }
});
```

What I now need to do is access properties of the collection within the model to determine the playback logic (i.e. if the current track playing was the last one in the collection).

Of course I could just pass the parameters through the play() function in the collection, but there has to be a much easier way to let models and collections based said model talk to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A model knows its collection. You can access it by `this.collection`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Excuse me for being so bold and saying that I am a moron :D